# how to safely stop mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, linux, debian

I (well, my cron script) tried `killall mysqldump` and that didn't end very well - mysql server stopped accepting connections after a while.

It was Debian Jessie machine with `mysql 5.5.55-0+deb8u1`.

Usage scenario was:

- there was a long running (few hours) `SELECT` query which was either really that slow or the client that sent it was having problems (query state was `Sending data`), but all the other queries were happily coming and going (only the load was perhaps little higher).
- in the night backup was being run with `mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 --hex-blob --single-transaction --master-data --routines --order-by-primary --databases db1 db2 db3... | pigz -p8 > backup.sql.gz`. It never finished, probably because it was waiting for the `SELECT` above to finish first (guessing here - it was only thing which looked out of ordinary, and same setup worked OK for months).
- cron job run in the morning, which had `killall -q mysqldump` which was supposed to safely terminate backup in case it was not finished by set time (notifying the admin to examine and fix the problem later), thus allowing people to continue working with mysql server normally.
- result however was full connection table and thus no user able to log in to mysql server. There was `FLUSH /*!40101 LOCAL */ TABLES` query stuck in `Waiting for table flush` and hundreds of `SELECT` queries stuck in same `Waiting for table flush` state.
- in addition, admin killing `LOCK TABLES` mysql query didn't help, as other SELECT queries remained in `Waiting for table flush` (which seems to be [intended behavior?](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44884))

Restarting mysql server finally "fixed" the problem.  However, Wanting to avoid this situation (and emergency admin interventions) repeating , I'd like to **safely** terminate mysqldump backup in Debian Jessie mysql-5.5.55 (or upcoming Debian Stretch mariadb-10.1.23-8). Is there a way?

If not, what are other options for accomplishing mysql backup and avoiding server load in the morning (which is - in this case - almost as bad as completely hung server)?

(I'd like to stay with Debian Stable packages if at all possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Mannoj, I've replaced simple "killall -q mysqldump" with smarter version which should solve the problem. It looks for all queries older than 4 hours in state "Waiting for table flush" and kills them (and produces processlist so issue can be debugged next day).

I call it from cron(8) at two times:

- at 11pm - right before I start backup (so the backup actually starts even if some long-running SELECT were still running at the time)
- at 7am with "hard" argument - right before people start coming to work (to restary mysql server in case nobody can connect to it)

```
#!/bin/sh
killall -q mysqldump
sleep 3
mysql -BNe 'show processlist' | \
  perl -nE '($id,$u,$h,$db,$cmd,$time,$state,$info) = split /\t/; 
  if (($time > 4*3600) and ($cmd =~ /Query/)) { 
          $found++; say "show processlist;" 
          if ($found==1); say "kill $id;" 
  };' | mysql -v

if [ "$1" = "hard" ]
then
  sleep 30
  mysql -BNe 'show processlist'  | grep -q 'Query.*show processlist' ||  /etc/init.d/mysql restart
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `--master_data` to take a consistent value of master status.

The internals of mysqldump will issue below commands to mysql server.

```
2017-05-31T04:39:05.843130Z    48 Query /*!40100 SET @@SQL_MODE='' */
2017-05-31T04:39:05.843273Z    48 Query /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */
2017-05-31T04:39:05.843411Z    48 Query FLUSH /*!40101 LOCAL */ TABLES
2017-05-31T04:39:05.846031Z    48 Query FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK
2017-05-31T04:39:05.846166Z    48 Query SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
2017-05-31T04:39:05.846279Z    48 Query START TRANSACTION /*!40100 WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT */
2017-05-31T04:39:05.846413Z    48 Query SHOW MASTER STATUS
2017-05-31T04:39:05.846539Z    48 Query UNLOCK TABLES
..
..... Here it continues to take backup of data and structures .
```

***What had happened?:***

Your backup would have just started and there was a query that was going on running on a particular table for a longer period of time before even FLUSH TABLES command and didn't release the lock on the table and `FLUSH TABLES` must have been waiting for that thread to get completed or keep trying to flush until the revision_version of that table is same as all tables.

Thus you get other threads blocked for other tables as well. As this is entire DBs*.Tables* level lock while flush tables was going on. Finally it would have got accumulated every new connection in processlist and piled up until `max_connections` and not allowing anyone to login.

Let's say if you have managed to login to the terminal and tried to kill flush tables, I don't think there is a way to pull back or rollback the flushed tables that has been done and release its own thread connection. So it might in a `KILLED STATE` for longer time. And thus you might have reached the last option that is to restart the server.

***How to fix it?:***

At the time of issue, when admin managed to login to mysql prompt.

Instead of issuing kill command on FLUSH TABLES thread, **if kill was given to the thread running for long SELECT**.There are chances that SELECT would have dropped and table is left FLUSH TABLES to acquire and update revision_version and release the lock for new queries. And backup would have continued. Since I don't think anyone expecting an answer on the other end waiting for the result for query running long hrs.

***What is the long term solution?:***

- You have to ensure no such long time queries to be running at the time of backup.
- Looks like this could be a new deployment or someone triggered a bad query and didn't bother to close the session.
- Try to kill the query if a query is running more than Xsecs (Depends upon your requirement). 
        Or
- Have an adjustment with the teams to tune the queries or send it to Admin to give them the result data or give them a separate slave all together.

Answer (score 0):

Because the reputation limit for comment, I guess there are 2 options to test, and I think to safely to stop mysqldump is not good way to solve this problem.

## `max_allowed_packet`

Is your database suddenly gain more big these day?

It shows 2G allowed.

If your data more than 2G will hang the process.

## No no-lock table hint

You can try `--lock-tables=false` or `skip-add-locks` in `my.cnf` to disable table locked.